# Is it possible to only git force push if remote is on a specific commit?

Tags: git

Say I want to squash the last 3 commits on master; forcing push might erase commits introduced in the meantime.

Doing:

```
git fetch master
git rev-list origin/master --max-count=1
git push // only push if hash returned by above is not new
```

Will not work if commits are pushed by 3rd parties between `git rev-list` and `git push`.

Comment: Check the man page for `git-push` and look for `force-with-lease`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called "force with lease" and is available on any *modern* Git server.  There are, however, a lot of old (not-modern) Git versions out there, so you must check to see whether the server supports this option.  If the remote server Git version is at least 1.8.5, it has the option.  (Your client needs the option too, of course, but at least here you have control: if your Git is ancient, you can install a newer one.)

If the server does have the option, simply run:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin branchname
```

to have your Git call up the Git at origin, hand it your new commit(s) as needed, and then have the server replace the server's `branchname` if and only if your own `origin/branchname` matches the server's `branchname` as of this very moment.  If the server's `branchname` *doesn't* match, you can then run `git fetch origin` to update your own `origin/branchname` to see what has happened in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Totally protected way to run it is

```
git push --force-with-lease=master:<output of the `git rev-list`> origin master
```

it also protects from some background `git fetch` happened after the `git rev-list`

Answer (score 0):

First of all [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307976/is-it-possible-to-only-git-force-push-if-remote-is-on-a-specific-commit/51308390#answer-51308241) is absolutely right.
and to complete his answer for older versions:

Yes you can count the number of commits between your local branch
and remote and if your counter is > 0 do your force

```
# count the number of commits between local and remote 
git rev-list --count master...origin/master

# if there only a single commit 
if [ $count -eq 1 ]; then

    # do a force push as your request   
    git push .......
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, however this does not solve the "extraneous commits between rev-list and push" issue